# OAuth2 client - redirect url not allow localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, openid-connect, siteminder, oauth2client

Creating a Springboot oauth2 client to integrate an OIDC provider login in the application.
But the OIDC provider not allowing redirect URLs (working on authorization code flow) with the format of http://localhost: or http://localhost

So every time I want to deploy the code changes to the server to check its working and not able to debug in my development environment.

I'm using my company-provided machine for the development, which not allow to install ngrok.

Can someone please help me to find a way to do the development and debug in my dev machine.

Comment: Which OIDC provider? If you deploy it to your "server" then the redirect has to be to "https://yourserver/. . . .".

Comment: also, often you will have problems with your cookies if you are using HTTP, HTTPS is today less problematic.